# Trouble understanding Product Notation

Tags: numerical-methods, gaussian-integral

[image]

I'm trying to determine the quadrature formula when the interval is [−2, 2] and the nodes are −1, 0, and 1.

However, I get stuck on this step because I don't understand how the attached image is equal to $1/2x(x-1)$

My attempt is, $(x - 1)/(-1 - 1)$ and $(x - 2)/(-1-2)$ but that is completely off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose from your setup that $x_0 = -1$, $x_1 = 0$, and $x_2=1$.
Then

\begin{align}
\prod_{j=1}^2 \left(\frac{x - x_j}{x_0 - x_j}\right) 
&= \left(\frac{x - x_1}{x_0 - x_1}\right) \left(\frac{x - x_2}{x_0 - x_2}\right)\\
&= \left(\frac{x - 0}{(-1) - 0}\right) \left(\frac{x - 1}{(-1) - 1}\right)\\
&= \left(\frac{x}{-1}\right) \left(\frac{x - 1}{-2}\right)\\
&= \frac{x (x - 1)}{(-1)(-2)}\\
&= \frac{x (x - 1)}{2}\\
\end{align}

It looks like your first attempt was to substitute $1$ for $x_1$ and $2$
for $x_2$, which, as you found out, does not work.